Find the portfolio with the maximum return at a given risk level using the `fPortfolio` package in `R`
I’m trying to find the portfolio with the maximum return at a given risk level using the fPortfolio package in R. However, there appears to be a bug in the package that the optimal portfolio (based on max returns) does not change when changing the target risk level, suggesting that it is not taking into account the target risk level specified by the user. This issue has been identified by others (see links below), and I provide a minimal reproducible example below. As far as I can tell, this issue has not been addressed in the package documentation (archived here) or in the authors’ book on fPortfolio (archived here). The bug was described nearly 10 years ago and it still hasn’t been fixed, so I figured we could turn to the community to help address it. My goal in creating this issue is to summarize what is known, identify potential issues with the package code, and hopefully get help to address it.
Here are the StackOverflow issues on this issue:

Setting target risk in R package fPortfolio (archived here)
Using target risk or target return in R package fPortfolio (archived here)

Here is a minimal reproducible example:
library("quantmod")
#> Warning: package 'quantmod' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> Loading required package: xts
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> Loading required package: TTR
#> Warning: package 'TTR' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
library("fPortfolio")
#> Warning: package 'fPortfolio' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> Loading required package: timeDate
#> Warning: package 'timeDate' was built under R version 4.3.2
#> Loading required package: timeSeries
#> Warning: package 'timeSeries' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'timeSeries'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:zoo':
#> 
#>     time<-
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:graphics':
#> 
#>     lines, points
#> Loading required package: fBasics
#> Warning: package 'fBasics' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'fBasics'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:TTR':
#> 
#>     volatility
#> Loading required package: fAssets
#> Warning: package 'fAssets' was built under R version 4.3.3
library("dplyr")
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.3.2
#> 
#> ######################### Warning from 'xts' package ##########################
#> #                                                                             #
#> # The dplyr lag() function breaks how base R's lag() function is supposed to  #
#> # work, which breaks lag(my_xts). Calls to lag(my_xts) that you type or       #
#> # source() into this session won't work correctly.                            #
#> #                                                                             #
#> # Use stats::lag() to make sure you're not using dplyr::lag(), or you can add #
#> # conflictRules('dplyr', exclude = 'lag') to your .Rprofile to stop           #
#> # dplyr from breaking base R's lag() function.                                #
#> #                                                                             #
#> # Code in packages is not affected. It's protected by R's namespace mechanism #
#> # Set `options(xts.warn_dplyr_breaks_lag = FALSE)` to suppress this warning.  #
#> #                                                                             #
#> ###############################################################################
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:timeSeries':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:xts':
#> 
#>     first, last
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Download historical stock prices
symbols <- c("AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOGL", "AMZN", "JNJ", "JPM", "V", "PG", "XOM", "TSLA")
quantmod::getSymbols(symbols)
#>  [1] "AAPL"  "MSFT"  "GOOGL" "AMZN"  "JNJ"   "JPM"   "V"     "PG"    "XOM"  
#> [10] "TSLA"

# Calculate stock returns
prices <- do.call(merge, lapply(symbols, function(sym) quantmod::Cl(get(sym))))
returns <- na.omit(TTR::ROC(prices, type = "discrete"))

returns_ts <- timeSeries::as.timeSeries(returns)

# Create portfolio
portfolioSpec <- fPortfolio::portfolioSpec()

# Identify tangency portfolio
tangencyPortfolio <- fPortfolio::tangencyPortfolio(
  data = returns_ts,
  spec = portfolioSpec)

# Extract optimal weights for tangency portfolio
fPortfolio::getWeights(tangencyPortfolio)
#>  AAPL.Close  MSFT.Close GOOGL.Close  AMZN.Close   JNJ.Close   JPM.Close 
#>  0.21136483  0.12495822  0.01223435  0.18743248  0.00000000  0.00000000 
#>     V.Close    PG.Close   XOM.Close  TSLA.Close 
#>  0.23495738  0.06078310  0.00000000  0.16826965

# Define target risk levels
targetRisks <- seq(0, 0.3, by = 0.01)

# Initialize storage for optimal portfolios
optimalPortfolios <- list()
optimalWeights_list <- list()

# Find optimal weightings for each target risk level
for (risk in targetRisks) {
  # Create a portfolio optimization specification with the target risk
  portfolioSpec <- fPortfolio::portfolioSpec()
  fPortfolio::setTargetRisk(portfolioSpec) <- risk
  
  # Solve for the maximum return at this target risk
  optimal_portfolio <- fPortfolio::maxreturnPortfolio(
    returns_ts,
    spec = portfolioSpec)
  
  # Store the optimal portfolio
  optimalPortfolios[[as.character(risk)]] <- optimal_portfolio
  
  # Store the optimal portfolio weights with risk level
  optimal_weights <- fPortfolio::getWeights(optimal_portfolio)
  optimalWeights_list[[as.character(risk)]] <- c(RiskLevel = risk, optimal_weights)
}

optimalWeightsByRisk <- dplyr::bind_rows(optimalWeights_list)
optimalWeightsByRisk
#> # A tibble: 31 × 11
#>    RiskLevel AAPL.Close MSFT.Close GOOGL.Close AMZN.Close JNJ.Close JPM.Close
#>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1      0        0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  2      0.01     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  3      0.02     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  4      0.03     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  5      0.04     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  6      0.05     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  7      0.06     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  8      0.07     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#>  9      0.08     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#> 10      0.09     0.0276          0      0.0282     0.0466     0.393         0
#> # ℹ 21 more rows
#> # ℹ 4 more variables: V.Close <dbl>, PG.Close <dbl>, XOM.Close <dbl>,
#> #   TSLA.Close <dbl>

sessionInfo()
#> R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22631)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8 
#> [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
#> [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
#> 
#> time zone: America/Chicago
#> tzcode source: internal
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] dplyr_1.1.4         fPortfolio_4023.84  fAssets_4023.85    
#>  [4] fBasics_4032.96     timeSeries_4032.109 timeDate_4032.109  
#>  [7] quantmod_0.4.26     TTR_0.24.4          xts_0.14.0         
#> [10] zoo_1.8-12         
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] utf8_1.2.4          generics_0.1.3      bitops_1.0-7       
#>  [4] robustbase_0.99-3   slam_0.1-51         lattice_0.22-6     
#>  [7] digest_0.6.36       magrittr_2.0.3      rneos_0.4-0        
#> [10] evaluate_0.24.0     grid_4.3.1          fCopulae_4022.85   
#> [13] mvtnorm_1.2-5       fastmap_1.2.0       jsonlite_1.8.8     
#> [16] energy_1.7-11       fansi_1.0.6         kernlab_0.9-32     
#> [19] truncnorm_1.0-9     XML_3.99-0.17       numDeriv_2016.8-1.1
#> [22] ecodist_2.1.3       mnormt_2.1.1        cli_3.6.3          
#> [25] rlang_1.1.4         Rglpk_0.6-5.1       gsl_2.1-8          
#> [28] reprex_2.1.1        withr_3.0.0         yaml_2.3.9         
#> [31] tools_4.3.1         parallel_4.3.1      mvnormtest_0.1-9-3 
#> [34] boot_1.3-30         curl_5.2.1          R6_2.5.1           
#> [37] vctrs_0.6.5         stats4_4.3.1        lifecycle_1.0.4    
#> [40] fs_1.6.4            MASS_7.3-60.0.1     Rsolnp_1.16        
#> [43] pkgconfig_2.0.3     pillar_1.9.0        fMultivar_4031.84  
#> [46] glue_1.7.0          Rcpp_1.0.13         tidyselect_1.2.1   
#> [49] tibble_3.2.1        DEoptimR_1.1-3      xfun_0.46          
#> [52] rstudioapi_0.16.0   knitr_1.48          spatial_7.3-17     
#> [55] htmltools_0.5.8.1   igraph_2.0.3        rmarkdown_2.27     
#> [58] compiler_4.3.1      quadprog_1.5-8      sn_2.1.1           
#> [61] RCurl_1.98-1.16

Created on 2024-07-23 with reprex v2.1.1
Here is the package code for the maxreturnPortfolio() function:
> fPortfolio::maxreturnPortfolio
function (data, spec = portfolioSpec(), constraints = "LongOnly") 
{
    data = portfolioData(data, spec)
    if (is.null(getTargetRisk(spec))) {
        stop("Missing target risk for maximum return optimization.")
    }
    else {
        Solver = match.fun(getSolver(spec))
        portfolio = Solver(data, spec, constraints)
        setWeights(spec) = portfolio$weights
        setStatus(spec) = portfolio$status
        Title = "Return Maximized Efficient Portfolio"
    }
    portfolio <- feasiblePortfolio(data, spec, constraints)
    portfolio@call <- match.call()
    portfolio@title <- Title
    portfolio
}

It appears to call the feasiblePortfolio() function:
> fPortfolio::feasiblePortfolio
function (data, spec = portfolioSpec(), constraints = "LongOnly") 
{
    Data <- portfolioData(data, spec)
    if (inherits(data, "fPFOLIODATA")) 
        data <- getSeries(Data)
    assetsNames <- getUnits(Data)
    Spec <- spec
    Constraints <- portfolioConstraints(Data, spec, constraints)
    if (is.null(getWeights(spec))) {
        stop("Missing weights")
    }
    weights <- as.vector(getWeights(spec))
    names(weights) <- assetsNames
    if (inherits(getSeries(Data), "timeSeries")) {
        targetReturn <- c(mean = (Data@statistics$mean %*% weights)[[1]], 
            mu = (Data@statistics$mu %*% weights)[[1]])
        setTargetReturn(spec) <- targetReturn
        Cov <- Data@statistics$Cov
        cov <- sqrt((weights %*% Cov %*% weights)[[1]])
        if (getType(spec) == "SPS") {
            myCheck <- TRUE
            funSigma <- match.fun(getObjective(spec)[1])
            rcov <- funSigma(as.vector(weights))
        }
        else {
            Sigma <- Data@statistics$Sigma
            rcov <- sqrt((weights %*% Sigma %*% weights)[[1]])
        }
        alpha <- getAlpha(spec)
        returns <- getDataPart(getSeries(Data)) %*% weights
        VaR <- quantile(returns, alpha, type = 1)
        CVaR <- VaR - 0.5 * mean(((VaR - returns) + abs(VaR - 
            returns)))/alpha
        targetRisk <- c(cov, rcov, -CVaR, -VaR)
        names(targetRisk) <- c("Cov", "Sigma", "CVaR", "VaR")
        alpha <- getAlpha(Spec)
    }
    else if (inherits(getSeries(Data), "logical")) {
        targetReturn <- c(mean = (Data@statistics$mean %*% weights)[[1]], 
            mu = NA)
        setTargetReturn(spec) <- targetReturn
        Cov <- Data@statistics$Cov
        cov <- sqrt((weights %*% Cov %*% weights)[[1]])
        targetRisk <- c(cov, NA, NA, NA)
        names(targetRisk) <- c("Cov", "Sigma", "CVaR", "VaR")
        alpha <- NA
    }
    covRiskBudgets <- (weights * Cov %*% weights)[, 1]/cov^2
    names(covRiskBudgets) <- assetsNames
    Portfolio <- new("fPFOLIOVAL", portfolio = list(weights = weights, 
        covRiskBudgets = covRiskBudgets, targetReturn = targetReturn, 
        targetRisk = targetRisk, targetAlpha = alpha, status = getStatus(spec)))
    new("fPORTFOLIO", call = match.call(), data = Data, spec = Spec, 
        constraints = Constraints, portfolio = Portfolio, title = "Feasible Portfolio", 
        description = description())
}

As far as I can tell based on the code (and I’m no expert), the feasiblePortfolio() function seems to create and assign the target risk, not to accept it as an input from the user (i.e.,  targetRisk <- c(cov, rcov, -CVaR, -VaR)), although I’m not sure. As one SO user noted, “[It] seems to have something to do with the efficientPortfolio() function and the solver used in spec. Apparently no matter what targetRisk you input, the solver inputs an objective that corresponds to the Covyou get when you print the portfolio”.
Any help in helping to identify and fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

As stated here, when short sales are allowed optimizing for target risk using maxreturnPortfolio seems to works as expected, defining setSolver(portfolioSpec)= "solveRshortExact". For "LongOnly" optimizations the problem persists for long time as you said, and in that case maxreturnPortfolio always returns the min var portfolio optimization as a solution, that is wrong.
I propose a workaround for this case which is based on portfolioFrontier solution. The ideia considers the two nearest points to target risk in the frontier' risks, and make linear combinations of the two portfolios to iterate up to a desired tolerance for risk.
# Function to aproximated portfolio for a target risk (tar_risk)
# based on efficiente frontier estimation (Eff_front) by linear combination
# of two nearest risks in the frontier, for most convex problems
# like efficient frontier will work within a 'tolerance',
# for more restricted problems a verification of further restrictions
# must be implemented
# for "LongOnly" restrictions

Aprox_maxreturn_Portfolio <- function(tar_risk,Eff_front,tolerance){
  # get parameters from Eff_front
  covarest = getCov(Eff_front) 
  Expret = getMean(Eff_front)
  sigma= Eff_front@portfolio@portfolio$targetRisk[,"Sigma"]
  fret= Eff_front@portfolio@portfolio$targetReturn[,"mean"]
  fweights = Eff_front@portfolio@portfolio$weights
  n=ncol(fweights) # assets
  EFpoints = fret >= fret[which.min(sigma)] # the efficient points only
  fweights = fweights[EFpoints,]
  sigma = sigma[EFpoints]
  ransigma = range(sigma)
  if (!(tar_risk>=ransigma[1] & tar_risk<= ransigma[2]))
    stop("tar_risk is not inside efficient frontier risk interval ", round(ransigma,6),"\n")
  posrisk= which(diff(findInterval(sigma, tar_risk))==1)
  # iterate whithin a tolerance
  iniws = fweights
  diffrisk = 1e9
  while( diffrisk > tolerance){
    # linear combin adjacent ef portfolios
    wz = seq(0,1,length.out=100)
    fe=matrix(rep(0,n*length(wz)),nrow = length(wz), ncol=n, byrow=TRUE)
    colnames(fe)=colnames(fweights)
    for (i in 1:n) fe[,i]=wz*iniws[posrisk,i]+(1-wz)*iniws[posrisk+1,i]
    ExpRetPort=rep(0,length(wz)) #
    RiskPort=ExpRetPort
    for (j in 1:length(wz)){ ExpRetPort[j]=fe[j,]%*%Expret # exp ret
    specj = portfolioSpec(); setTargetReturn(specj) = ExpRetPort[j]
    effportj =  efficientPortfolio(getData(Eff_front), spec = specj, getConstraints(Eff_front))
    RiskPort[j] = getTargetRisk(effportj)["Sigma"]
    #RiskPort[j]=(t(fe[j,])%*%covarest%*%fe[j,])^.5 # risk
    } 
    posrisk= which(abs(diff(findInterval(RiskPort, tar_risk)))==1)
    diffrisk= abs(diff(RiskPort[c(posrisk,posrisk+1)]))
    iniws = fe
  }
  
  # compute final portfolio
  wopt=(RiskPort[c(posrisk,posrisk+1)]-tar_risk)/abs(diff(RiskPort[c(posrisk,posrisk+1)]))
  wopt = abs(wopt[1])
  tport =wopt*fe[posrisk,]+(1-wopt)*fe[posrisk+1,]
  tret=tport%*%Expret # exp ret
  tar_riskc=(t(tport)%*%covarest%*%tport)^.5 
  
  # solution
  list(portfolio=tport,return = tret, risk=tar_riskc )
}

Example:
# Create portfolio
portfolioSpec <- portfolioSpec()

Constraints = "LongOnly"
setNFrontierPoints(portfolioSpec) = 80 
Data = returns_ts

## Eff Frontier
Eff_front = portfolioFrontier(Data,portfolioSpec, Constraints)

#plot
frontierPlot(Eff_front, pch = 19, title =FALSE)
Eff_front@portfolio@portfolio$minriskPortfolio

c(min(Eff_front@portfolio@portfolio$targetRisk[,"Sigma"]),
  max(Eff_front@portfolio@portfolio$targetRisk[,"Sigma"]))
# solve a problem
tar_risk = 0.0091
tolerance = 1e-7

Aprox_maxreturn_Portfolio(tar_risk,Eff_front,tolerance)

$portfolio
 AAPL.Close  MSFT.Close GOOGL.Close  AMZN.Close   JNJ.Close   JPM.Close     V.Close    PG.Close   XOM.Close 
 0.04379226  0.00000000  0.02848604  0.05911637  0.36892972  0.00000000  0.02692962  0.36391607  0.09255214 
 TSLA.Close 
 0.01627778 

$return
             [,1]
[1,] 0.0004797394

$risk
            [,1]
[1,] 0.009100002

Simulation for several target risk
# simulate for several points
# Define target risk levels

targetRisks <- seq(0.009064718,0.035888956, by = 0.002)

# Initialize storage for optimal portfolios
optimalPortfolios <- list()
optimalWeights_list <- list()

# Find optimal weightings for each target risk level

for (risk in targetRisks) {
  # Create a portfolio optimization specification with the target risk
  portfolio1 = Aprox_maxreturn_Portfolio(risk,Eff_front,tolerance)
  # Store the optimal portfolio
  optimalPortfolios[[as.character(risk)]] <- portfolio1
  # Store the optimal portfolio weights with risk level
  optimal_weights <- portfolio1$portfolio
  optimalWeights_list[[as.character(risk)]] <- c(targetRisk = portfolio1$risk,
                                                 targetReturn=portfolio1$return,
                                                 targetRiskd  = risk,
                                                 optimal_weights)
}
optimalWeightsByRisk <- dplyr::bind_rows(optimalWeights_list)
optimalWeightsByRisk

#MAE
mean(abs(apply(optimalWeightsByRisk[,c(1,3)],1,diff)))

#[1] 2.612458e-08

Plot the two frontiers
# plot
upperFrontier <- frontierPoints(Eff_front, frontier = "upper", 
                                return = "mean", risk = "Sigma", auto = T)
dataefffront = rbind(data.frame(upperFrontier,Frontier="Efficient"),
                     data.frame(optimalWeightsByRisk[,1:2],Frontier="Approx"))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataefffront,aes(x=targetRisk,y=targetReturn,colour = Frontier))+
  geom_point()


